# Single node Kubernetes cluster - Containers in different pods can't communicate with each other

Tags: docker, kubernetes, redis

I have a reccuring problem with container in different pods can't communicate with each other.
To make things simple, I created a cluster with only 2 containers in different pods:

1. app that does only one thing: connecting to redis server.
2. redis-server container

To make long story short: I'm keep getting  'connection refused' when trying to connect from the app to redis:

```
$ kubectl logs app-deployment-86f848b46f-n7672

> app@1.0.0 start
> node ./app.js

LATEST
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.104.95.63:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1133:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '10.104.95.63',
  port: 6379
}
```

the app identidfy the redis-service successfully but fails to connect

```
$ kubectl get services
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
app-service     ClusterIP   10.107.18.112   <none>        4000/TCP   2m42s
kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP    29h
redis-service   ClusterIP   10.104.95.63    <none>        6379/TCP   29h
```

the app code:

```
const redis = require("redis");
const bluebird = require("bluebird");
bluebird.promisifyAll(redis);
console.log('LATEST');
const host = process.env.HOST;
const port = process.env.PORT;
const client = redis.createClient({ host, port });

client.on("error", function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

app's docker file:

```
FROM node
WORKDIR "/app"
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

for the redis server I tried the default image of redis, and when it didn't work, I used a custome-made image without any bind to a specific ip and no protected-mode.

redis dockerfile:

```
FROM redis:latest
COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
```

Finally, I've created 2 deployments with respected ClusterIP services:

app deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: app
    spec: 
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: user/redis-app:latest
        ports:
          - containerPort: 4000
        env:
          - name: HOST
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: app-env
                key: HOST
          - name: PORT
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: app-env
                key: PORT
```

app service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: app
  ports:
    - port: 4000
      targetPort: 4000
```

env file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: app-env
data:
   PORT: "6379"
   HOST: "redis-service.default"
```

redis deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      db: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        db: redis
    spec: 
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: user/custome-redis:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
```

redis service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: redis
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
```

Originally, I used Windows enviorment with WSL2 and Kubernetes running over docker with Docker Desktop installed. when it failed, I've provisioned a centos8 vm over virtualbox and installed kubernets with minikube - got the same results..

any ideas?....

Comment: Hi AbuJed, welcome to SO. It sounds like there is something in your `redis.conf` that is changing the address upon which redis listens. Have you checked the log output from the redis pod to see what it has to say? Have you tried, for debugging purposes, swapping in the "vanilla" redis image and see if this behavior persists? What troubleshooting steps have you already tried and what are there outcomes? Good luck

Comment: Your Service binds to Pods labeled with `component: redis`, but the Deployment creates Pods labeled `db: redis`.  These need to match.  If you `kubectl describe service refis-service`, it should say something like `Endpoints: <none>` which is a sign these don't match up.

Comment: David Maze thanks!! that worked things out..

Comment: @DavidMaze could you please post your comment as an answer on the question? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Posting an answer out of comments since David Maze found the issue (added as a community wiki, feel free to edit)

It's very important to match labels between pods, deployments, services and other elements.

In the example above, there are different labels used for `redis` service:

`component: redis` and `db: redis` which caused this issue.